# My API call is rendered twice in the router function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, next.js

Having NextJs Project and using express for routing. I coded a router with dynamic :id paramter. Once the :id is fetched I am creating an axios call to check it in the DB. But for some reason the API is called twice once :id entered in the browser. My reactStrictMode is OFF. Also there is no favicon problem. Assume :id is 12345 than the axios call is made twice with 12345 as parameter.

Below is my code.

```
const express = require("express");
const Axios = require("axios");
const next = require("next");
const dev = false;
const app = next({ dev });
const helmet = require("helmet");
require("dotenv").config()

const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");

appInsights
.setup(process.env.APPSETTING_AZURE_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY)
.setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
.setAutoCollectRequests(true)
.setAutoCollectPerformance(true)
.setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
.setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
.setAutoCollectConsole(true, true)
.setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
.setSendLiveMetrics(true)
.start();

let count = 0

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    server.use(express.json());
    const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

  const port = process.env.PORT || 5005;
  server.use(helmet.dnsPrefetchControl());
  server.use(helmet.expectCt());
  server.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
  server.use(helmet.hsts());
  server.use(helmet.ieNoOpen());
  server.use(helmet.noSniff());
  server.use(helmet.permittedCrossDomainPolicies());
  server.use(helmet.referrerPolicy());
  server.use(helmet.xssFilter());
  server.use("/", express.static("static"));

  const redirectHandler = (res,url) =>{
    if (url.indexOf("http") !== 0) {
      url = "https://" + url;
  }
  res.redirect(url)
  }

  

  server.get("/", (req, res) => {
    app.render(req, res, "/home", req.query);
  });


  server.get("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    count++
    const url = (new URL(`${process.env.APIM_URL}/campaign/${req.params.id}`));
    console.log("'/test' call...",count);
    Axios.get(url,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Basic ${process.env.APIM_BASIC}`,
          "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": `${process.env.SUBSCRIPTION_KEY}`,
        },
      })
      .then(function(response){
        if (response && response.data) {
          if(response.data.error){
            app.render(req, res, "/error", { code: response.data.error });
            return null;
          }
          else if(response.data.type==="redirect"){  
            redirectHandler(res,response.data.url)
            return null;
          }
          req.userInformation = response.data;
        }  else {
          app.render(req, res, "/error", { code: 404 });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => next(err));
  })

  server.get("*", (req, res) => handle(req, res));

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
})
.catch(() => {
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Example:
entered data: https://myurl.com/12345

consoled data:
test' call...",1
test' call...",2

Comment: You don't seem to have posted any React code here.

Comment: This my server.js main file. It has no react code.

Comment: Then remove the reactjs Tag,..  Please don't spam tags.. If it's not relevant, don't include it.   You also have this in your question -> `My reactStrictMode is OFF.`..   Your question seems to be slightly confused.. :)

Comment: Also any reason your going directly to `express` here?  You might find using `nextjs` dynamic routing would be better -> https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes  And a nice example -> https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-rest/pages/api

Comment: Do you have a `Next/Link` to this page? In this case, it might be the cause of the second call as it would try to prefetch it. Try adding `prefetch={false}`to the `Link`

Answer (score 0):

Axios.get() function is asynchronous. This means that the axios request is made after the count++ statement has executed. So, while the count has already incremented to 1 before the axios request is made, axios request will still made twice.